# One-to-many and one-to-one relationship mixed, how to?

Tags: mysql, database-design, one-to-one

My question might be dumb since I think it's a very common design issue, and I guess there is a simple and usual solution to it:

- I have a table Producer and a table Movie
- ONE Producer has produced MANY Movies
- ONE Producer has ONE favorite Movie among the ones he has produced

How do I implement this in MySQL?

1. just one ONE-TO-MANY relation between Producer and Movie, plus a 'favorite' boolean attribute in the Movie table
2. one ONE-TO-MANY relation to represent the 'has produced' relation, and a ONE-TO-ONE relation to represent the 'is favorite' relation

The first solution seems more natural to me, but when the producer wants to change his favorite movie, I guess the second solution is more efficient. As well as it should be more efficient to find a producer's favorite movie with solution #2.

What am I missing? Is there a best solution? If not in which case should I use solution #1 and solution #2?

(Of course, my problem is a bit more complex thant the example above...)

Comment: You're letting natural language fool you.  The relationship between users and movies isn't one to many, but many to many.  Therefore, that requires an extra table.

Comment: @MattFenwick I get your point, and indeed My example might not be the best one. A more accurate one would be : ONE producer has produced MANY movies, and ONE producer has ONE favorite movie among his movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (1) is not easy/efficient to enforce declaratively. Plus, you end-up wasting space on all non-favorite movies.

The (2) is the way to go. Unfortunately, this circular dependency will lead to the chicken-and-egg problem, which is solved:

- either by deferring one of the FKs (if the DBMS supports it, which MySQL unfortunately desn't),
- or by leaving the FK in user NULL-able, which is less than ideal since the user can now have zero or one favorite movies (as opposed to strictly one).

---

Assuming you want the same movie to be relatable to multiple users (making it a many-to-many relationship, not one-to-many as you stated), your model would end-up looking something like this in a DBMS supporting deferrable FKs:

[image]

But you don't have the luxury of deferring the constraints in MySQL, so you'll be forced to do something like this:

[image]

```
CHECK (FAVORITE_USER_ID IS NULL OR FAVORITE_USER_ID = USER_ID)
```

Comment: i like your answer. I guess the "you end-up wasting space on all non-favorite movies" part conviced me it is the wrong solution.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean attribute not only takes up a lot more space, but also looks like it would prevent more than one user from having a favourite.

The second solution sounds correct.  Have a field in User to represent each user's favourite and an additional table to make the one to many "has watched" relationship.

If you need to make sure that the user has actually watched his/her favourite movie, you should add that logic as a business rule in your data access object.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would go with solution 2. Along with making queries for the favorite simpler, this has the added benefit of a built-in constraint, limiting the user to having only one favorite movie. Furthermore, this will be slightly smaller, having one id per user instead of one boolean per watched movie-user. One side-effect, however, is that you are able to favorite a movie without watching it.

Solution 1 would be the preferred choice only if you wanted to extend your favorites system in the future to include more than one favorite. However, it would appear that this is explicitly not desirable.

---

It is also worth mentioning that the relationship between users and movies is many-to-many, not one-to-many, as *each* user has their own list of watched movies. Therefore you will need a third table to link the two. Unless of course you are just having a list of uncorrelated strings for each user, but I doubt this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there will always only be one movie I would have a "favorite movie ID" attribute in the user table, along with a many-to-many relation between users and movies (the same movie can be watched by many users)

So, three tables total, flag in the users table.

Comment: yeah, I changed the example to avoid the many to many relationship. If it were a many-to-many relationship, I guess I would just add a boolean in the relation table.

Answer (score 0):

I think second solution is more feasible. You can create two tables for these relations, one named HasWatched, the other one named Favorite. Both of these tables constist of two columns, named userId - movieId. The primary key for Haswatched table is (userId - movieId) tuple. But primary key of Favorite table is only userId. Therefore, you can apply all constarints.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a third table... I don't think is a one to many relation, its a many to many, one user can watch many films but one film can be watched by many users...

I would do a users table, a movie table, and a user-movie-watched table with user_id, movie_id
and add a favorite_movie field pointing the movie_id the user favs.